# Consequences of changing NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT

Tags: oracle, configuration

I administer a 9.2.0.8 database where the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is set to `'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM';`.

This leads to odd results when using the `CAST TO TIMESTAMP` function:

```
select CAST('14-SEP-2011' AS TIMESTAMP) "DATE" from dual;
----------
14-SEP-2020 11:00:00.000000 AM
```

If I alter the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` to `'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SSXFF AM'` then I am good to go.

Would changing the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` parameter on the database to `YYYY` have any consequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database-level `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` parameters are not particularly useful because they are always overridden by the client settings.  So even if you change the database setting, 99+% of the time when a user comes along and connects to the database, their session is going to set a `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` based on the client's `NLS_LANG` or other national language settings (i.e. applications using the thin JDBC driver use the JVM's internationalization settings rather than relying on the client `NLS_LANG`) and overrule the setting you made in the database.  There are a few corner cases involving database jobs using `DBMS_JOBS` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` where there is no client where the database `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` are used, I believe, but those are rather rare.

You could create a login trigger that did an `ALTER SESSION` to set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` for your sessions.  That would overrule the settings the client requested when it created the session.  As Nick points out, you'd have to worry that other queries are relying on the current setting for implicit conversions and your change might break that code.

In general, you're much better off avoiding implicit conversions wherever possible but particularly when it comes to converting strings to or from dates and timestamps simply because there are so many different formats that you're setting yourself up for problems.  If you want to specify a date literal in your code, you're much better using the ANSI date and timestamp syntax

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select cast( date '2011-09-14' as timestamp ) dt,
  2         timestamp '2011-09-14 13:15:30' ts
  3*   from dual
SQL> /

DT                             TS
------------------------------ -----------------------------------
14-SEP-11 12.00.00.000000 AM   14-SEP-11 01.15.30.000000000 PM
```

If you want to convert a string to a date or a timestamp, you're better off using a `TO_DATE` or a `TO_TIMESTAMP` with an explicit format mask.

Answer (score 0):

Existing queries that rely on this format may return different results.

Check if your existing code interprets `TIMESTAMP` fields in a way that is format-dependent, and be sure to update it if it does. Note also that `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` can be set at the database or client level, so take note of what format a client sees when it executes code.